# Object element call function in Vuejs

Tags: javascript, function, object, callback, vue.js

i want to use a function to set individual content of table cells.
In this example i want to wrap the status with the `<strong>` - Tag
(I dont edit the template, because at my application it's stored in a component, which is used multiple times ...)

```
tableData: [
  {
    "name": "test1",
    "status": "1"
  },
  {
    "name": "test2",
    "status": "0"
  },
  {
    "name": "test3",
    "status": "1"
  }
],
columns: {
  name: {
    title: "name"
  },
  status: {
    title: "status",
    content: function(entry) {
      return "<strong>" + entry.status + "</strong>";
    }
  }
}
```

I tried smth like `value.content.call()` in the `v-for` loop, but this doesnt work.

**JsFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/7anuorbu/4/

Comment: I think your approach is not good.You are keeping methods into the data object.

Comment: @Belmin is there another good way to do this?

Comment: The way you done It confuse me a bit.Why you didn't do basic iteration of your array, and then wrap your status value in strong tag in template ? Or if you want to go without putting strong tag directly in template, use computed property, or method do it for you.

Comment: @Belmin i dont want to change the template, how can i use computed property without editing the template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use help of [v-html](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML), which takes care of rendering of html in the views. In the HTML, you can call the function like this:

```
<tr v-for="entry in tableData">
  <td v-for="(value, key) in columns" v-html="value.content(entry)">
  </td>
</tr>
```

To make this work I have modified `columns` data as well, as both elements need to have content.

```
   columns: {
      name: {
        title: "name"        ,
        content: function(entry) {
          return "<span>" + entry.name + "</span>";
        }
      },
      status: {
        title: "status",
        content: function(entry) {
          return "<strong>" + entry.status + "</strong>";
        }
      }
```

Whole working code is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/7anuorbu/6/).

Comment: thanks - working!! i also added v-if to check if value.content is a function, so i dont have to add it everywhere :)